# What's the best practice for referencing 3rd parties JS library in Polymer custom element?

Tags: html, polymer, custom-element

Currently, I face some serious problem about duplicate referencing 3rd-parties library that causes some libraries to malfunction.

This is the first custom element.

```
<script src="../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<dom-module id="jquery-ui-menu">
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "jquery-ui-menu"
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

This is the another element.

```
<script src="../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<dom-module id="jquery-ui-popup">
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "jquery-ui-popup"
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

As you can see, both of this script tag refer to jQuery that locate in the same path. Normally, browser should load jQuery 2 times that cause some serious problem like the following code.

All registered event will be wiped out when jQuery is loaded second time.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('test', function (){alert('test!');});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).trigger('test');
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sry1shpt/

I think this is not the bug of jQuery or any other 3rd-parties libraries. But it's a serious problem of Polymer. It's totally nonsense to allow element load duplicated script.

Do you have any practical way to solve this problem?

*Please remember the source code of both elements may locate in difference repository and it should not know about each other.*

**Thanks,**

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `<script>` tags into a seperate HTML file (i.e. `jquery-scripts.html`) and use HTML imports in both custom elements:

`<link rel="import" href="jquery-scripts.html">`

HTML imports are de-duplicated and thus `jquery-scripts.html` and as a consequence the jquery library will only be imported once.

Comment: Thanks. I know about this way. But is it a standard way to implement it? I read about some guy in Polymer team wrote about using bower to solve about version of 3rd-parties libraries and relatively reference to libraries in bower folder.

Comment: Well AFAIK it's the only way to avoid that `jquery` is loaded twice. With `bower` you can manage your dependencies and it will put all of those into the `bower_components` folder and you can reference it using a relative path (this is important as the de-duplication feature works only for the same origin). However this doesn't solve your problem as a `script` tags are not de-duplicated by the browser (same library is downloaded twice). `HTML Imports` supports de-duplication and thus allows you to avoid downloading jquery twice.